# How to create complex Left JOIN in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to create multi Model Left join using django

Here is my model

```
class LookupTiming(models.Model):
    day = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    time_1 = models.TimeField()
    time_2 = models.TimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'lookup_timing'

class Streets(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    point = models.GeometryField(null=True, blank=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'streets'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name


class StreetTimings(models.Model):
    street= models.ForeignKey(Streets)
    lookuptiming = models.ForeignKey(LookupTiming)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'street_timings'
```

This is query that i have created

```
Streets.objects.filter(streettimings__isnull=True).filter(streettimings__lookuptiming__isnull=True).values('id')
```

This is sql output of above query

```
SELECT "streets"."id" FROM "streets"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "street_timings" ON ( "streets"."id" = "street_timings"."street_id" ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "street_timings" T3 ON ( "streets"."id" = T3."street_id" )
WHERE ("street_timings"."id" IS NULL AND T3."lookuptiming" IS NULL)
```

But i want following query

```
select st.id from streets st
LEFT JOIN street_timings timing on timing.street_id = st.id 
LEFT JOIN lookup_timing lt on lt.id = timing.lookuptiming_id
```

So problem is that, the django query total ignore **lookuptiming** Model. I want to create following joins

```
Streets(id) = StreetTimings (street_id)

LookupTiming (id) = StreetTimings (lookuptiming_id)
```

How can i create left join for multiple models?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is about your Django Query

```py
Streets.objects.filter(streettimings_isnull=True).filter(streettimings_lookuptiming__isnull=True).values('id')
```

`streettimings_isnull=True` will return `Streets`  which do not have a `StreetTiming` relation. So, using `streettimings_lookuptiming__isnull=True` is meaningless since filtered `Street` objects do not have a related `StreetTiming` relation. Try following

```py
LookupTiming.object.values_list("streettimings__street__id", Flat=True)
```

If it do not create expected query, yuou may try following

```py
LookupTiming.object.filter(streettimings__street__isnull=False).values_list("streettimings__street__id", Flat=True)
```

That will return you all `Street.Id` values. You have to use reverse relations to create the query you wanted.

**Update:** You **must** use the relations in fitlering (or some other parts o the Query Api) so Django will create `joins`. If you do not provide any filtering data, django will not create `joins` since it would not require them.

You can try following, but even it will create a `WHERE` clause.

```py
Streets.objects.filter(streettimings_lookuptiming__id__gt=0).values('id')
```

Comment: your query is creating inner join and also ignore LookupTiming. this is output        SELECT "streets"."id" FROM "streets" 
INNER JOIN "street_timings" ON ( "streets"."id" = "street_timings"."street_id" )
WHERE "street_timings"."lookuptiming" IS NOT NULL

Comment: This query will be work for LookupTiming, but i want to create join for Streets and also i cannot add more Model for join in this query

Comment: More Model means, i have just show two model for join but actual query   contain more than two Models.

Comment: I think your previous query is correct but queryset is creating some extra filter, i don't know how i can exclude these filters.

Comment: this is the extra filter, any idea how can i remove this            WHERE "streettimings"."lookuptiming _id" IS NULL

Comment: Which one? Your sql do not mean anything to me because you just show the `joins` you want to have in your query. Without any use of those joins, you can not create what you want from `Streets` model. Because if you want to use `Streets` class to form your query and you need `Streets.id`, then you simply write `select id from streets;`

Comment: this was your query, but it is creating extra filter Streets.objects.filter(streettimings_lookuptiming__isnull=False).values('id')

Comment: (WHERE "streettimings"."lookuptiming _id" IS NULL) at the end of query

Comment: I am talking about that. You must provide some filtering data which is using `streettimings_lookuptiming__` relation so Django will build joins. Without using that, django will not create joins since that they will not used. Anouther approch might be `Streets.objects.filter(streettimings_lookuptiming__id__gt=0).values('id')` which will filter `LookupTiming.id` that are gereater than 0. You **must** use the relation so django should create the joins.